# Android Studio and gradle home issue - Ubuntu

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04
Android Studio Version 3.6.3

I think I have two installed Gradle locations If I'm not wrong
One of them installed using sdkman, when I use terminal to locate the Gradle

```
which gradle
```

[image: Terminal]

Also, I've found (I don't remember if I installed Gradle in another way instead of sdkman) in my home directory, this is the one which Android Studio is using (I think) and make issues when opening a project
[image: Gradle other directory]
[image: Android Studio Gradle settings]

I think I need to use sdkman as it's easier to update the Gradle version etc.
So, my question is should I remove the gradle from: "/home/khaledomara/.gradle". If so, what is the best method to do that and what path should I put in the settings of Android studio?
Should it be "/home/khaledomara/.sdkman/candidates/gradle/current/bin/gradle"?

Answer (score 0):

You only have one Gradle installed - the ~/.gradle directory is where a running Gradle process stores data and it can be safely deleted (assuming you don't have a gradle.properties or similar with any settings you want to save - but there is no need to delete it).

It is not a bad idea to do a gradle init in your Android Studio project - this will give your project its own Gradle that you can upgrade at your leisure without having to rely on the globally installed Gradle.